# R2DBC and Transient fields

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc

I would like to mark a field in entity as transient, however any annotation is being ignored.

```kotlin
    @Transient
    override var aaa: List<Zzz> = mutableListOf(),
```

Getting:

```
Dialect org.springframework.data.r2dbc.dialect.MySqlDialect does not support array columns
```

Comment: what version is project working with ?

Comment: Newest, Spring boot 3.1.2.

Comment: i've been through and i need exclude the @transient field from constructor ....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@jakarta.persistence.Transient`
if you use `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` it works properly.

I checked it in spring-boot 3.1.3.